# Codeacademy console broke?

Tags: javascript, console

I am working on Codeacademy.com's. The console won't pass it. I contacted them, but does anyone see anything wrong with my code?

Section 4/7, Problem 5. "The Story Heats Up."

```
console.log("Batman glares at you.");
var userAnswer = prompt("Are you feeling lucky, punk!?", "");
if(userAnswer.toLowerCase() === "yes"){
    console.log("Batman hits you very hard");
} 
else{
    console.log("You did not say yes to feeling lucky.");
}
```

Linked Tutorial:
http://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-beginner-en-x9DnD/0/5?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661#

Comment: Looks ok to me - http://jsfiddle.net/5Bm8z/ - what browser are you using?

Comment: I've tested it on Chrome and FF.

Comment: You mean in the console you don't get the text? do you get it in the fiddle?

Comment: The code does function properly in the console and displays the correct if/else message response, based on my prompt answer. I just think there's something I am missing that the console wants to see to give me the green light so I can move on to the next problem.

Comment: Your code is ok. If you mean the red message on code academy, ignore is. You do have a if statement so its correct. Otherwise the console is a browser debugging tool, you get it pressing F12 on the browser.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. CA wasn't giving me credit; it's console wanted me to format the answer another way.  It's a little finicky.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
//Check if the user is ready to play!
confirm("Are you ready?");

var age=prompt("How old are you?");

if (age>17){
console.log("play on");
}
else
{
console.log("i don't care");
}
//Story
console.log("Snow White and Batman were hanging out at the bus stop, waiting to go to the shops. There was a sale on and both needed some new threads. You've never really liked Batman. You walk up to him.");
console.log("Batman glares at you");

var userAnswer;
var userAnswer=prompt;
prompt("are you feeling lucky?");
if (prompt==="yes")
console.log("Batman hits you very hard. It's Batman and you're you! Of course Batman wins!");
else
console.log("You did not say yes to feeling lucky. Good choice! You are a winner in the game of not getting beaten up by Batman.");
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. It turns out that this exercise only works when it contains the previous exercises